# What's the best way to get other properties of the logged in user in Java Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

So, by using the line below we can extract the username and password:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

But I would like to get the userId of the logged in user, a property of my custom User class. so I decided to do this:

```
        CustomUserDetails details = new CustomUserDetails(); 
        ...
        details.setUser(current);
        UserDetails myUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(details, myUserDetails);
        CustomUserDetails myDetails = details.downCast(myUserDetails);
        Integer userId = myDetails.getUser().getId(); //Fetch the custom property in User class
        user.setId(userId);
```

However, I am just getting the user through HQL and putting it inside a temporary User class, which is pointless.

So, what's the best way to get the property userId? It seems I am better off just using a HQL query (get the User through HQL with the username of the logged in user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend the Spring Security `UserDetails` class and add whatever appropriate attributes that are of interest your application needs.  We typically do this specifically for immutable information which includes `userId`.

Then when you need the appropriate attribute:

```
// Get the principal from spring security
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

// verify principal if your custom user details type.
// if so, get the userid and do whatever.
if(principal != null && principal instanceof CustomUserDetails) {
  CustomUserDetails userDetails = CustomUserDetails.class.cast(principal);
  Long userId = userDetails.getUserId();
  /* do whatever you want with user id */
}
```

Then during authentication, just create your own `CustomUserDetails` object when your implementation of `UserDetailsService` returns the `UserDetails`.

Comment: My application uses the class public class UserDetailsServiceImpl which implements UserDetailsService and has a method that returns userDetails. I could just return customUserDetails after adding an user to it inside the method, right? I am not sure if I can return something else than userDetails though.

Comment: @jarvan You can most definitely create an instance of the extended class `CustomUserDetails` and return it as it's super class type `UserDetails` from that function.

Comment: Can I return it as it is or do I have to cast it?

Comment: @jarvan Return it as is, just override the method.

Comment: Oh wow, it works. You can return a subclass of UserDetails containing any number of class + the User class.